# What is best method to update image tag to commit SHA via CloudBuilder?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I have a **deployment.yaml** containing deployment of *3 containers* + *LB service* and the **cloudbuild.yaml** containing *steps to build container images every time there's new commit to a certain branch on Bitbucket git repo*.

All is working fine except the fact that my deplyment isn't updated whenever there's a new image version (*I used :latest tag in deployment*) and to change this I understood that my deployment images should use something unique, other than :latest, such as a git commit SHA.

Problem:
**I'm not sure how to perform image declaration update during GCB CI process to contain new commit SHA.**

YAML's: https://paste.ee/p/CsETr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution by using image tag or URI variables in deployment fine and substituting them with sed during build-time.

**deplyment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init
        image: INIT_IMAGE_NAME
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -r /app /srv; chown -R 82:82 /srv/app']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: code
          mountPath: /srv
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: NGINX_IMAGE_NAME
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: code
          mountPath: /srv
        - name: php-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health.html
            port: 80
            httpHeaders:
            - name: X-Healthcheck
              value: Checked
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health.html
            port: 80
            httpHeaders:
            - name: X-Healthcheck
              value: Checked
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
      - name: php
        image: PHP_IMAGE_NAME
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: code
          mountPath: /srv
        - name: php-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health.html
            port: 80
            httpHeaders:
            - name: X-Healthcheck
              value: Checked
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health.html
            port: 80
            httpHeaders:
            - name: X-Healthcheck
              value: Checked
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
      volumes:
        - name: code
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: php-socket
          emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: app-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: app
```

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:

# Build Images
- id: Building Init Image
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build','-t', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/init:$SHORT_SHA', '-f', 'init.dockerfile', '.']

- id: Building Nginx Image
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build','-t', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/nginx:$SHORT_SHA', '-f', 'nginx.dockerfile', '.']
  waitFor: ['-']

- id: Building PHP-FPM Image
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build','-t', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/php:$SHORT_SHA', '-f', 'php.dockerfile', '.']
  waitFor: ['-']


# Push Images
- id: Pushing Init Image
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['push','eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/init:$SHORT_SHA']

- id: Pushing Nginx Image
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['push','eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/nginx:$SHORT_SHA']

- id: Pushing PHP-FPM Image
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['push','eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/php:$SHORT_SHA']


# Update Image Tags
- id: 'Setting Init Image Tag'
  name: ubuntu
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,INIT_IMAGE_NAME,eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/init:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']

- id: 'Setting Nginx Image Tag'
  name: ubuntu
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,NGINX_IMAGE_NAME,eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/nginx:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']

- id: 'Setting PHP Image Tag'
  name: ubuntu
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,PHP_IMAGE_NAME,eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/php:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']


# Update Deployment
- id: Updating Deployment
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
  args: ['apply','-f','deployment.yaml']

  env:
    - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west2-b
    - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=clusterx

# Images
images:
  - eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/init:$SHORT_SHA
  - eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/nginx:$SHORT_SHA
  - eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/php:$SHORT_SHA

# Tags
tags:
  - master
  - dev
  - init
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kubernetes won't pull an image that it has already (as it uses the same tag `:latest`).

I think your system would benefit of using the new tag:

```yaml
- id: Updating Deployment
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
  args: ['set', 'image', 'deployment/app', 'nginx=eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/nginx:$SHORT_SHA']
  env:
    - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west1-b
    - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cluster-1
```

(You would have to also set the image for the other containers.

Another technique would be to update your deployment file with the new tags, and apply the whole file.

Comment: Yes, something like that, but I'd prefer if I could apply one file (deployment.yaml) which contains all pod images instead of updating images one by one like you suggested. I'm looking into sed build step to change deployment.yaml image variable names to those generated by the GCP on the fly..

Comment: You should be able to update your deployment file with the new tags as suggested by "Philippe", and apply the whole file.